# Incrementally Increment Identical Integers

Tags: code-golf, array

<sub>Inspired by [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70550089/17242583).</sub>

Given an ascending-sorted array of possibly duplicated integers, your goal is to increment each number by a counter, starting at 0, that resets for each group.

Spec:

- Any numbers may be negative (but if so, they'll be at the beginning, because the array is sorted),
- The array will have at least one element,
- There may be any number of integers in one group
- The groups of numbers have nothing to do with one another

To demonstrate:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40]
```

should become this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11, 20, 21, 22, 30, 40, 41, 42, 43]
```

because

```
  1 1 1 1   10 10   20 20 20   30   40 40 40 40
+ 0 1 2 3    0  1    0  1  2    0    0  1  2  3
  -------   -----   --------   --   -----------
  1 2 3 4   10 11   20 21 22   30   40 41 42 43
```

### Test cases

```
input -> output
[1, 2, 3] -> [1, 2, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] -> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 1, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100] -> [1, 2, 10, 11, 100, 101, 102, 103]
[-5, -5, -5, -5, -4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9] -> [-5, -4, -3, -2, -4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can there be elements repeated "outside" their group, such as `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]`? What would the output for that be, `[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2]` or `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing No, because the input is sorted.

Comment: What happens to [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 19, 19, 20, 20]

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/178500/9288)

Comment: @Stilez you'd add `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 0, 1]` to it, to get `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 19, 20, 20, 21]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 3 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Perfect challenge for BQN's *occurence count* builtin.

```
+⟜⊒
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK+KfnOKKkgoKPuKLiOKfnEbCqCDin6gx4oC/MuKAvzMKMeKAvzHigL8y4oC/MuKAvzPigL8zCjDigL8w4oC/MOKAvzDigL8wCjHigL8x4oC/MTDigL8xMOKAvzEwMOKAvzEwMOKAvzEwMOKAvzEwMArCrzXigL/CrzXigL/CrzXigL/CrzXigL/CrzTigL804oC/NOKAvzTigL804oC/OeKAvzkKMeKAvzHigL8x4oC/MeKAvzLigL8y4p+p)

The modifier `⟜` composes two functions. If there is a single argument (as is the case here), the right function is called on that argument, and then the left function is called with that result and the original argument:

```
(f⟜g x) ≡ (x f g x)
```

The builtin `⊒` takes a vector and returns for each element how many times the same value appeared before:

```
(⊒ 1‿1‿1‿10‿10‿100) ≡ 0‿1‿2‿0‿1‿0
```

The result of `⊒` is then added element-wise to original input by `+`:

```
(1‿1‿1‿10‿10‿100 + 0‿1‿2‿0‿1‿0) ≡ 1‿2‿3‿10‿11‿100
```

---

Ports of other more interesting answers:

- [`⊢+⊒˜-⊐˜`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oqiK+KKksucLeKKkMucCgo+4ouI4p+cRsKoIOKfqDHigL8y4oC/Mwox4oC/MeKAvzLigL8y4oC/M+KAvzMKMOKAvzDigL8w4oC/MOKAvzAKMeKAvzHigL8xMOKAvzEw4oC/MTAw4oC/MTAw4oC/MTAw4oC/MTAwCsKvNeKAv8KvNeKAv8KvNeKAv8KvNeKAv8KvNOKAvzTigL804oC/NOKAvzTigL854oC/OQox4oC/MeKAvzHigL8x4oC/MuKAvzLin6k=), [DLosc in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240425)
- [`(⊢+˝=⌜×⊒<⌜⊒)˜`](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKOKKoivLnT3ijJzDl+KKkjzijJziipIpy5wKCj7ii4jin5xGwqgg4p+oMeKAvzLigL8zCjHigL8x4oC/MuKAvzLigL8z4oC/Mwow4oC/MOKAvzDigL8w4oC/MAox4oC/MeKAvzEw4oC/MTDigL8xMDDigL8xMDDigL8xMDDigL8xMDAKwq814oC/wq814oC/wq814oC/wq814oC/wq804oC/NOKAvzTigL804oC/NOKAvznigL85CjHigL8x4oC/MeKAvzHigL8y4oC/MuKfqQ==), [Luis Mendo in MATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240426)

Comment: Very concise, I don't understand it but it looks cool. If possible, will you please provide a small explanation? :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Brilliant.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

*2-byte savings jointly contributed by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748) and [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546)*

```python
lambda L,j=1:[n-(j:=j-1)-L.index(n)for n in L]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BDoIwELz3FRNONNkaKppok/oCfoA9YIAI0UKgB319tRAUTWY2O5PJ7vRPd@1seugHX@uzvxX3S1kgo1ZLlVsRt0q3QnKRbRpbVo/Y8robYNFYZMa7anQjNHKGXBK2hNTQvM8yOIuZEL5YxWSy8H9MIbEn/HBHWOP4xvra57VhhoWyoWToO5VVDP3QWBcHRYjEKSLUk@LcvwA)

#### Explanation

The original 48-byte solution is easier to explain:

```python
lambda L:[n+i-L.index(n)for i,n in enumerate(L)]
```

Consider each number \$n\$ in the list together with its index \$i\$. Suppose that we are looking at the \$k^{th}\$ occurrence (0-indexed) of the number \$n\$. We want to add \$k\$ to the number. Since identical numbers are adjacent, the index of the \$0^{th}\$ occurrence of \$n\$ will be at index \$i-k\$. This is the result of `L.index(n)`, meaning \$k\$ is `i-L.index(n)`. Add that value to \$n\$ for each element of the list, and we're done.

To get the 46-byte solution, we track the index using a variable instead of `enumerate`, updating it in the list comprehension using Python 3.8's "walrus operator" `:=`. We could track the actual index \$i\$:

```python
lambda L,i=-1:[n+(i:=i+1)-L.index(n)for n in L]
```

but it saves a byte to track \$j \equiv -i\$ instead, because we can initialize it to `1` instead of `-1`.

Comment: Save a couple of bytes by moving to 3.8+ and using the walrus operator with `lambda L,i=1:[n-(i:=i-1)-L.index(n)for n in L]` (dingledooper also posted this a few seconds after me, so dual credit is fine!)

Comment: I figured there might be something with `:=` that was shorter than `enumerate`, but counting backward to save a byte in the initialization is really clever!

Answer (score 10):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
+i.@#-i.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tTP1HJR1M/Xq/mty@TnpKURbWds4aIBFNfX16rhSkzPyFdIUDHWQkAEEGyFhYyA2QcH/AQ)

Basically a port of [DLosc's python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240425/15469), which fits naturally in the array paradigm.

### how

Consider `1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40`

- `i.~` Index of each element's first appearance:

  ```
  0 0 0 0 4 4 6 6 6 9 10 10 10 10
  ```
- `i.@#-` Subtract that from `0 1 2 ... n`:

  ```
  0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 2 3
  ```
- `+` Add that to the original input:

  ```
  1 2 3 4 10 11 20 21 22 30 40 41 42 43
  ```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
t&=XRs+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v0TNNiKoWPv//2hDHQUQMoBhdCIWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L9EzTYiqFj7v0vI/2hDHQUjHQXjWC4QC8IB8ZGFDA1gGJ0AKgEyEIg4LbqmOgoo2ERHARlZAhHCJLirYgE)

#### How it works

Consider input `[1, 1, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100]` as an example.

```
t    % Implicit input. Duplicate
     % STACK: [1 1 10 10 100 100 100 100], [1 1 10 10 100 100 100 100]
&=   % Matrix of equality comparisons 
     % STACK: [1 1 10 10 100 100 100 100], [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                            1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
                                            0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
                                            0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
                                            0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
XR   % Upper triangular part, without the diagonal
     % STACK: [1 1 10 10 100 100 100 100], [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                                            0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
                                            0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
                                            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
                                            0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
s    % Sum of each column
     % STACK: [1 1 10 10 100 100 100 100], [0 1 0 1 0 1 2 3]
+    % Add, element-wise. Implicit display
     % STACK: [1 2 10 11 100 101 102 103]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŒɠḶF+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opJMLHu7Y5qb9/3D70UkPd87QjPz/P5or2lBHwUhHwThWB8yE8EACUDEDHQUEQigyNIBhdAKkRtdURwEFm@goICNLIEIyC25tLFcsAA)

### How it works

```
ŒɠḶF+ - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
Œɠ    - Group run lengths
  Ḷ   - Zero based range
   F  - Flatten
    + - Add elementwise to L
```

For example, take `L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`:

- `Œɠ`: `[2, 2, 2]`
- `Ḷ`: `[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]`
- `F`: `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`
- `+`: `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] + [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]`

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. I can't believe it can be done with so little code! :D

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 33 bytes

*Edit: -7 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe.*

```r
function(a)a+sequence(rle(a)$l)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNCsIwDMfvPkVADw220M6peNAXEQ@jVBiMitM9f43Z2tpaktL@88sHGUNP5xzuk7fv/uFFh9325Z6T89aJcXAkbAZUhjlhhZHQSNghrkFd4Lp8b6scnqWv@sctooQ2JWgJ2SKtY5UCnWsbHb2@yl7MmBTlF8t5WLWXUHhL7X7sRBaLxriikVSTWFIPEo7MGl2PmpZRrYtTeW@I4QM)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZDNCsIwDMfvPkVADw220M6peNAXEQ@jVBiMitM9f43Z2tpaktL@88sHGUNP5xzuk7fv/uFFh9325Z6T89aJcXAkbAZUhjlhhZHQSNghrkFd4Lp8b6scnqWv@sctooQ2JWgJ2SKtY5UCnWsbHb2@yl7MmBTlF8t5WLWXUHhL7X7sRBaLxriikVSTWFIPEo7MGl2PmpZRrYtTeW@I4QM)

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, the `sequence` function... Forgot about it. Thanks!

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZZDNDsIgDMfvPkWNFxpLAnNqPOiLGA8N0biDM@p8fsRugCBpCfz760f69F04e395927o7r1i5OXr/FBzRn3jwV0VE6NQyilL0BCsEBegD3CcvqdZDo/SV/3jJpGgTQmGIFukTaxSoGNta6LXV9lLGJui8hI5D6vXBIW3od2P7YLFojGuw0i6SWxQNwRbYa2pR03LqNYlqbI3RP8B) porting [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240439/67312), or at least its explanation.

Comment: @Giuseppe - i think it's distinct enough for a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 11 bytes

```
gr+>zW(+)nn
```

### Explanation

Most of this is pretty simple

- `gr` is "group"; it groups a list into a list of equal segments.
- `zW` is "zip with"; it takes a function and uses it to combine two lists pairwise.
- `(+)` is "plus"; it adds things.
- `nn` is "the natural numbers"; an infinite list of all non-negative numbers in order.
- `zW(+)nn` combines the last 3 into a single thing which takes a list and adds every element with its index.

The last thing here that links `gr` with `zW(+)nn`. The `+>` operator.  This operator has a name it's called "Kleisli composition".  Regular composition takes functions `a -> b` and `b -> c` and produces a third function `a -> c`, Kleisli composition does very similar.  It takes Kleisli morphisms, which are just a particular kind of function, that maps into a monad.  So `a -> m b` where `m` is a monad would be an example of a function from `a` to `m b`, but is a Kleisli morphism from `a` to `b`.

So Kleisli composition takes a function `a -> m b` and a function `b -> m c` and produces a function `a -> m c` where `m` is some monad.

This is in fact sort of the fundamental essence of a monad, that Kleisli composition forms a category.  So how are we using it here?

Well we have `gr :: List a -> List (List a)` and `zW(+)nn :: List a -> List a` and the thing we want is `List a -> List a`. A naive way to do it would be to group the whole thing map across each element and the concat everything back up:

```
jn<m(zW(+)nn)<gr
```

However an experienced Haskell golfer will notice that map and then concat is exactly the monad behavior of the `List`.  So we could potentially get a bind to do the concat and the map in one go.

And now if we look at the types we can see they fit the shape of Kleisli morphisms.  So we can actually, compose, map and concat all at once using Kleisli composition.

Answer (score 5):

## Scala, 43 bytes

```scala
s=>s.indices.map(i=>s(i)+i-s.indexOf(s(i)))
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sEZcMudCRjSsj3EGXOuJeQ)

A port of [DLosc's great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240425). Go upvote that!

### My original answer, 48 bytes

```scala
s=>s.distinct.flatMap(x=>x to x-1+s.count(x.==))
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7WxItEEnTQODkMZO1M3iaw)

This one gets distinct elements, then for every element `x`, it makes a range from `x` to `x + n`, where `n` is the number of occurrences of `x`.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (tcc)](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc), <del>56</del> 54 bytes

```c
c;f(int*p,int*q){for(c=0;p-q;*p+=++c)c*=!(*p-*++p-c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDbboMgGL7nKf65bAHBRVfvqHsRZ4wBTEkcUqW7mPHZHbQaLeHj8MN3AJE4IZZF8BZr42LLwnglU9sPWBQpt8mVx5YWlAoi4uIFxzaJKbWJIHxeXrUR3U0qOI9O6v7j8oXQb68l2MHr1J0eHR71n6oddMow8EWQjWvKisCEwLf7xRZHZUT4veCNYeNoKCDlfjoHul9QuvGO3DfJIGIPYV2tOvOTfPVtgsGMUIjw02iDN6VQcGp0tWhGVWZ55U2njMHe0wc@Dzh55E@Y1/j4fRdLKwaHbXbawh2@J8vZbr8eD8rdBuOfjublHw)

- -2 bytes thanks to [pxeger](/users/97857/pxeger)

This is a rather straightforward port of my suboptimal [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240429/43394). Takes a pointer to the beginning and end of the array.

### Explanation

```c
c;  /* int c; (thanks pxeger) */
f(
    int *p,  /* pointer to the first integer */
    int *q   /* pointer to the last integer */
) {
    for (
        c=0;  /* initialise the increment */
        p-q;  /* reached the end? (if so, stop) */

        /* note: these run out of order */
                         *p+=++c)
        c*=!(*p-*++p-c);
        /*
            equivalent to:
                int original_p0 = p[0] - c;  // undo increment
                if (original_p0 != p[1]) {
                    c = 0;  // different, so reset counter
                }
                p[1] += c;
                c += 1;
                p += 1; // move to next p
        */
}
```

Comment: You can declare `c` outside the function so you don't need the `int`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDZboQgFH3nK25t2rDZaMc3xv6INcYgtiQWGWH6UOO3W5zR6BAOy4WzgIy/pJxnKVqsjaeWL@OFjG0/YJknwsYXQS3LGZNE0vwJUxtTxmwsiZjmZ21kd20UnJ1vdP/2/YHQb68bsEPQqTrtPHb6T1UeOmU4hCI0ta@LksCIILTbxRZHRUTErRCMYeNoyCERYTov9LBgbOMduS8Nh4jfhXW56kwP8uWnWQwmhJYIP7U2eFNaCl45X8naqSLNymA6phz2ntzxfsApIHvAtMbHr7tYUnI4bNPTFu7wPWnGd/v1eFD@OpjwdDTN/w "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger I knew there was some kind of trick for that! Thanks.

Comment: I was also going to suggest removing the `int`s from the function parameters, but I don't really understand why you need it.

Comment: @pxeger I couldn't get it to compile with them gone. I *shouldn't* need them.

Comment: @pxeger Oh, I remember. Omitting the type is the legacy syntax, but the legacy syntax for function parameters _isn't_ putting them in the `()`.

Comment: Fails for the second test case and similar, btw you can omit parameter type in Clang.

Comment: Building on @AZTECCO [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVDbboQgEH33KyY2bVCxUdzuw7K2H2KJMV5aEovsSvtQ47dbcDVis2ROgIFzyZRh2RbiY5oUbZAvsX/xhqa7IpX6ksogCC/U82WqQl@@md5JZmHMgpiO0wMXZftd1XDuVcW7589Xx/npeAXyyoXKW94r1PPfOlfQ1gKDbkJVqCJjHgwO6DV/bJCbuR6dG9oZVg6HFCKqt7Oh60MQrDyb@1hhcPFNmLNFZ9zJs3dhDEbHMRG@Ci7QqmQaqu5VXhZ9nTFtOcQYtopuIBYSjcMO4xIePW1SEcNgXeNkjWYNJz7gzXx53gUidiIyV6Lrjh/5Z0iylzuGR8uPmIlMfw "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
function(a)a+seq(!a)-match(a,a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDNDsIgDMfvPkWNFxpLAnNqPOiLGA8N0biDM@p8fsRugCBpCfz760f69F04e395927o7r1i5OXr/FBzRn3jwV0VE6NQyilL0BCsEBegD3CcvqdZDo/SV/3jJpGgTQmGIFukTaxSoGNta6LXV9lLGJui8hI5D6vXBIW3od2P7YLFojGuw0i6SWxQNwRbYa2pR03LqNYlqbI3RP8B)

Port of [Jonah's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240439/67312). Uses 1-based indices but it makes no difference.

Test harness taken from [pajonk's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240433/110034).

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##ZZDNDsIgDMfvPkUTLzSWBObUeNAXMR4I0biDM875/Fi7AYKkfP3760c6hI7XIVzfvR@7R68cutXr8uRb393ob8qRQ4GUV5agIVgjLkEf4TR/z4vsnqSv@sfNIkGbAgxBtkibmKVAp9zWxF0fZS1hbPLKS@TcrN4QFLvlcj@2Z4tJo19zS7pJLKtbgp2w1tStpmFU45JQmRti@AA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: That won't work; try it with `iiii(5)`. R functions sometimes have different behavior with length-one input (`sample` is another), to the chagrin of R golfers.

Comment: My bad! Thanks for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
ṁGo→Kg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY3u@Y/aJnmn////PzraUMdIxzhWB0iDWEA2mGegA4VQGUMDCELBQDldUx0EMtGBQUsdS5hGiLGxsQA)

```
     g  # group equal elements
ṁ       # then map the following onto each group
        # (concatenating the results):
 G      #   scan from left
        #   (arg1=result so far, arg2=next element)
  o     #   combination of 2 functions:
    K   #     constant function (= arg1)
   →    #     incremented
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
L,dBG€bL€RbFz£+dbL1Xz£_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HJ8XJ/VHTmiQfIBGU5FZ1aLF2SpKPYQSQEf9fJScxNyklUcHQzp7L////aF1TBQQyUYBBSwXLWAA)

### Explained

```
L,dBG€bL€RbFz£+dbL1Xz£_
L,                       # create a lambda that:
  d                      # pushes two copies of the input
   BG                    # ... groups the second on consecutive items
     €bL                 # ... gets the length of each of those groups
        €R               # ... creates the range [1...n] for each of those lengths (add++ doesn't have a range [0...n) built-in for some reason dang it caird.)
          bF             # ... flattens that list
            z            # and zips it with the original input. This creates a list of items and how much to increment by
             £+          # now, reduce each item by addition
               dbL       # and push the length of the list, keeping a copy on the stack of the original list
                  1X     # push a list of length(^) 1s
                    z£_  # and subtract that from each item in the other list (this is just to account for the fact that there's no [0...n) built-in)
```

Comment: Wow, I see a lot of money in that code :P - Will you please provide a small explanation? They're very interesting.

Comment: upvote later - used all my votes on other answers :)

Comment: @richardec of course, I'll write up an explanation - I was actually in the process of doing so and found a way to shave 3 bytes off lol

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>75</s> 66 bytes

```
B+A,[C]-->[A],{C is A+B},B+1+A;[X],{C=X},1+X.
_+_-->[].
a-->0+x,!.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/30nbUSfaOVZX1y7aMVan2lkhs1jBUdupVsdJ21Db0To6AiRoG1GrY6gdoccVrx0PUhmrx5UIpA20K3QU9f7/T9SINtRRgCMjIIrVcdLUAwA)

This program can be run by calling the grammar `a//0` to parse the input list. The remainder after parsing will be unified with the output list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
Ġvẏf+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoHbhuo9mKyIsIiIsIlsxLDEsMSwxMCwxMCw0LDQsMiwyLDIsMiw1LDYsNiw2XSJd)

-1 thanks to lyxal

```
Ġ     # Group runs of identical chars
 vẏf  # 0...n each and flatten
    + # Add to input
```

Port of [caird coinheringaahing's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240422).

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoHbhuo9mKyIsIiIsIlsxLDEsMSwxMCwxMCw0LDQsMiwyLDIsMiw1LDYsNiw2XSJd) for 5 bytes

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>61</del> 60 bytes

I wrote this answer to make sure my algorithm was sound, before I [implemented it in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240436/43394).

```python
def f(a,b=.5,c=0):
 for d in a:c*=not d-b;yield d+c;c+=1;b=d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcNLCoAgEADQfaeYpZZF300yJ4kW6SQJoVFuOr0FLSp4bzvD4l0TI80GDJuEwqITGkveJ2D8DgTWwdTrFJ0PQLmSp51XAsq01BlWUiHFbbcusNUegRk2VAJe5bP@bO7t78g5jxc)

### Explanation

```python
def f(
    a,     # input list
    b=.5,  # previous value
    c=0    # consecutive counter
):
    for d in a:
        c *= not d-b;  # if d and b are different, c = 0
        yield d + c;
        c += 1;
        b = d          # next loop, this'll be the previous value
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>22 17</s> 10 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to ovs!

```apl
∊{⊂⍺+⍳≢⍵}⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXFyPeucqBOTnVKZl5uQopOUXKZTmZRaWpirkJhZnc4UC1VRXG9pq6z/q3Wp7aL3ho7aJQFbtoRU6MSD6fxpQwaOOrupHXU2PendpP@rd/KhzEUjmUc@O///TFAwVjBSMuUA0iAVkg3kGMAiVMTSAIBQMlDu03hQNmyjAoKWCJUw3xGwA)

Comment: Your first approach can be simplified with the *Key* operator `⌸` to `∊{⊂⍺+⍳≢⍵}⌸`

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
+ċṪ$Ƥ
```

A monadic Link accepting a sorted list of integers that yields a list of integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7SPfDnatUji35//9/tK6pjgIKNtFRQEaWQBQLAA)**

#### How?

```
+ċṪ$Ƥ - Link: list of integers, A
    Ƥ - for prefixes of A:
   $  -   last two links as a monad, f(prefix):
  Ṫ   -     pop off the tail from the prefix
 ċ    -     count occurrences of that in the remaining prefix
+     - A add that (vectorises)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 bytes

```perl
s/-?\d+/$&-$f?$i=0:$i++;$i+($f=$&)/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX9c@JkVbX0VNVyXNXiXT1sBKJVNb2xpIaKik2aqoaeqnp/7/b6hgpGDMZagAooEsINtAAQrBooYGEISCuXRNFRDIRAEGLRUsIZogxv3LLyjJzM8r/q@bWAAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 38 bytes

```
p=.5
for x;echo $[(c=p-x?0:c+1)+(p=x)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY31Qps9Uy50vKLFCqsU5Mz8hVUojWSbQt0K-wNrJK1DTW1NQpsKzRjIaphmgyiDXQUgEjXFA2b6CggI0swMjSIhWoEAA)

I think there might a solution abusing `mv`'s backup functionality like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35950), but I can't work out how.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 12 bytes

```perl
$_+=$h{$_}++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXttWJaNaJb5WW/v/f11TLgQy4YJBSy7Lf/kFJZn5ecX/dQtyAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://python.org) + [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), 40 bytes

```
lambda L:S(L)+S(L).groupby(L).cumcount()
```

The code doesn't run on TIO, since it's `pandas`...

But anyway, [here](https://tio.run/##XU7LDoIwELz3KyacaCwGRA@S4Bdw44gcyktJhDZtOfD1SCEomszszkw2uytH8xR9ODVKdJC8r7hG20mhDNJatbXGHKSkie/Ti3dFxZFEqZvQgy3HhxKDLEYry6ErxdAbl06m1kYjRkaQBQwnhjBnq16tTbbQZ/hiNxb4G//LMuRdGH54ZtjjOmO/7XM6JzlphIJ9Em2/dB0RSNXOz1vH4Hg3h6FZHKXTGw) is the code.

Comment: Haha, this is nice ;)

Comment: @richardec Yup!

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 machine code, 15 bytes

```
3b 06 74 02 31 c9 ad 29 4e fc ff cf e0 f2 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLTsMwEDzbX7EYISVpWgpEHFLKj5QcjB@pwXnITquqVX@dsLErWiSPd3Z3xl7ZYl4LMY7cN5BQtqht98ktaEbZR@tUr/hQEtMKUPIQakQ0PSh@yGHjvKli7UuB/zZ9SHRJDp2b9PmfaWqWxHbSy2jgUgb/vKiuKiLVdI@5nNkeIQ4Qc6eQpCu674wEnZh2gDaHKWQcy/c4pN1JBW9@kKZbbN8pnZoNN20Qc1eLHMSWO8gyTPYpPVESOpsK1nB6yuG6lhHPN3hBFP9wXsUDLNq9OapOJzx9vLAwFdGJzSEyfJQwiEH1coXhbg0W42yWQu@woxP2YIChfmOqydLvBp8whvQ8jj9CW177cd68Frjhh63Ro@wv)

Following the standard calling convention for Unix-like systems (from the System V AMD64 ABI), this takes the length of the array in RDI and the address of the array of 32-bit integers in RSI. The starting point is after the first 4 bytes.

Assembly:

```
.global f
repeat:
    cmp eax, [rsi]      # Compare last value and current value
    je skip             # Jump if they are equal
f:
    xor ecx, ecx        # (If not equal, or at the start) ECX = 0
skip:
    lodsd               # Put the current value in EAX, and advance the pointer
    sub [rsi-4], ecx    # Subtract ECX from the (same) value
    dec edi             # Count down from the length
    loopnz repeat       # Jump back if not finished, also reducing ECX by 1
    ret                 # Return
```

Here is another solution I found, at 16 bytes, taking the arguments in the opposite order:

```
.global f
f:
    mov eax, edx
repeat:
    cmpxchg [rdi], edx
    cmovne edx, eax
    inc edx
    scasd
    dec esi
    jnz repeat
    ret
```

Comment: Wow, this is a language-ish I haven't head of. Cool, thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 51 bytes

```
x=>x.map((y,i)=>y+x.reduce((r,z,k)=>r+=z==y&k<i,0))
```

Comment: `x=>x.map((y,i)=>x.reduce((r,z,k)=>r+=z==y&k<i,y))`

Answer (score 2):

## APL+WIN, 22 bytes

Prompts for input vector

```
v+¯1++⌿p×+\p←<⍀v∘.=v←⎕
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tf5n2ofWG2tqPevYXHJ6uHVMAlLF51NtQ9qhjhp5tGZAHVP8fqJLrfxqXoYKRgjEXiAaxgGwwz0ABCqEyhgYQhIKBcofWmyqgYhMFGLRUsITphpgNAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
ＩＥθ⁺ι№…θκι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyEgp7RYI1NHwTm/FCRTmZyT6pyRD5bK1tRRyNQEAev//6OjDXUUEMgAgo2QsDEQm6Dg2Nj/umU5AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Does not require the array to be sorted or grouped. Explanation:

```
  θ         Input array
 Ｅ          Map over elements
    ι       Current element
   ⁺        Plus
     №      Count of
         ι  Current element in
      …θκ   Prefix of input
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Alternative approach, also 10 bytes, but requires the array to be grouped:

```
ＩＥθ⁺ι⁻κ⌕θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyEgp7RYI1NHwTczD8jI1lFwy8xLAUlkaoKB9f//0dGGOgoIZADBRkjYGIhNUHBs7H/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ         Input array
 Ｅ          Map over elements
    ι       Current element
   ⁺        Plus
      κ     Current index
     ⁻      Minus
       ⌕    First index of
         ι  Current element in
        θ   Input array
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Comment: _"Does not require the array to be sorted"_ - That's a cool bonus!

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 68 bytes

```
r(`(?<=(^|,)(\3,)*)((-)?\d+)
#$#2$*1$4$3$*
+`1-1
-
#(-)?(1*)-?
$1$.2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCsJADETv@Y2NkGwTaXbroaDs0Z8oZQU9ePFQPPrva@tWSpkJ80jITI/383UrB7rmMlGmdL7Q@BGmIQp7JlJOw71hcOgCesMOI3posqmBglvuZJ41ARoeQykmQSKYLDnTzK2s@m2trd4N6Ek2d/JXL319qnVf) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
r(`
```

Use right-to-left matching for the whole script, as that allows the matches to be specified slightly more golfily.

```
(?<=(^|,)(\3,)*)((-)?\d+)
```

Match each integer, and count how many times it's been repeated.

```
#$#2$*1$4$3$*
```

Replace each integer with a marker `#`, the repetition count in unary, and the integer in unary. Note that if the integer is positive this already adds the count to the integer.

```
+`1-1
-
```

If the integer was negative then find the difference between it and the count.

```
#(-)?(1*)-?
$1$.2
```

Convert the integer back to decimal, ignoring a trailing `-` sign, which indicates that the count was at least as large as the absolute value of the integer and therefore the result is no longer negative.

28 bytes in [Retina 1](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) if only non-negative integers need to be supported:

```
r`(?<=(\2,)*)(\d+)
$.(*_$#1*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8L8oQcPexlYjxkhHU0tTIyZFW5NLRU9DK15F2VDr/39DHSMdYy5DHRANZAHZBjpQCBY1NIAgFAyRgegBAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
r`(?<=(\2,)*)(\d+)
```

From right to left, match each integer, and count how many times it's been repeated.

```
$.(*_$#1*
```

Add the number of repetitions to the integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 44 bytes

```
[ dup '[ over + swap _ index - ] map-index ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/NCsIwEITvfYq5eZBK6x@oDyBevIinUiS0Ww3GNCapWqXPHltrizKzMB/DLmzGEptrt99ttuslzqQlCWS6xIXZEwxdC5IJGRxJkmaCP5nluTRQmqwtlebSYuV5L4QYY4Lqk5rcUMtBr64Ng9b/07T@7MdTdFrU6pe/5yvPRUgLhUGE/EYaQ5g7UziAy5Qe8BHXTyi/pdjNIZlSosTIIBHEtHsD)

Port of @Dlosc's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240425/97916).

`dup '[ ... _ ... ]` slots a copy of the input into the quotation at the `_`. `map-index` is like `map` except it also places the index on the stack in addition to the element.

There were a lot of other approaches and attempts; the last three are just longer versions of the above.

```
[ histogram >alist [ first2 over + 1 <range> ] map-concat ]
[ [ ] group-by values [ dup length iota v+ ] map-flat ]
[ histogram [ over + 1 <range> ] f assoc>map concat ]
[ dup '[ _ overd index -rot + - abs ] map-index ]
[| l | l [ | n i | n i + l index - ] map-index ]
[| l | l [ over + swap l index - ] map-index ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü ®í+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CCu7Ss&input=WzEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDMsIDNd)

```
ü      - group
  ®    - for each
   í+  - zip with index then sum
```

Comment: Not sure a 2D array is valid output but you can fix it by replacing the map with `c_`.

Comment: @Shaggy isn't std out enough? I mean the program prints a list

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

```
g[#]++&/@((g@#=#)&/@#)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pz1aOVZbW03fQUMj3UHZVlkTyAQS/wOKMvNKopV17dIclGPV6oKTE/PqqrmqDXWMdIxrdUAMEBPIgXANdKAQJmdoAEEoGCSpa6qDQCY6MGipYwnXCjEamQsxzQiGjA10TBColqv2PwA)

```
          (g@#=#)&/@#   initialize g[x]=x for each x in input
g[#]++&/@(           )  post-increment g[x] for each x in input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>66</s> 61 bytes

```
:group_by+:next|:values|:*&(:zip%(:size|:*)|:*&:sum)|:flatten
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9ItTar8n2b73yq9KL@0ID6pUtsqL7WipMaqLDGnNLW4xkpLTcOqKrNAVcOqOLMqFcjXBIlZFZfmAhlpOYklJal5/wsU0vQ0og11FBDIAIKNkLAxEJug4FjN/wA)

<s>Surely there is a way to improve this.</s> Yep, `+` is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

Requires Ruby version 2.7 or newer.

```ruby
->a{a.tally.flat_map{[*_1.._1+_2-1]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY3VXXtEqsT9UoSc3Iq9dJyEkvicxMLqqO14g319OINteONdA1ja2uhigMLFNKiow11FBDIAIKNkLAxEJug4NhYLiSdRmBkDESxsRCDFyyA0AA)

###### A quick rundown:

`->a{X}` is an anonymous lambda function taking a parameter `a` and returning `X`.

`tally` returns a hash with each unique number in the input list and the number of times that number appeared in the list.

`[*1..4]` returns `[1,2,3,4]`.
`flat_map` returns a flattened list from the result of the given `{code block}` being run on each number/count pair returned by `tally`, where `_1` is a placeholder for the number and `_2` is the count. So for example with an array with 5 `2`s, `[*_1.._1+_2-1]` returns `[2,3,4,5,6]`.

Comment: Now _this_ is interesting. Will you please provide an explanation? Though I know next to nothing about Ruby, I can get along well enough with normal-looking code, but by submitting this, you golfed by brain right out of my head... :P

Comment: @richardec hehe, thanks. I added a quick explanation in the post. It's not much to it really, it might just look a bit messy/weird. The tally method is doing most of the heavy lifing here.

Comment: Thanks! It's really quite understandable now, even for a non-Ruby guy like me. Your explanation is concise and practical ;) The `*_1..` was seriously stumping me... :P

Comment: btw ATO has an updated version of ruby where the polyfill can be omitted: [Try It!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhY31XXtEqsT9UoSc3Iq9dJyEkvicxMLqmsydfJqorUy9fQytfN0DWNra6HKAwsU0qKjDXUUEMgAgo2QsDEQm6Dg2FguJJ1GYGQMRLGxEIMXLIDQAA)

Comment: @Razetime cool, thanks

Answer (score 2):

### [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), 5 bytes

```
!$,~~+-@?_
```

That's 10 nibbles which are encoded in 0.5 bytes each. Nibbles isn't on TIO yet.

Translation:

```
!       zip
 $      the input list
 ,~     1..
 ~      (by a function, as opposed to 1 op zip) \x y->
   +
    -
     @  y
     ?  index
      _ the input list
      implicit x
    implicit y
```

Usage: pass the input in via the command line i.e.

```
nibbles filename.nbl "[1,1,1,1,10,10]"
```

Command line args used instead of stdin because input int list would still be 1 nibble in its second use (DeBruijn indicies incremented by 2 from the zip).

This is basically the same as DLosc's solution in Python (adding the difference of the index from its position)

Comment: Interesting! I hadn't heard of Nibbles. What do you mean by _"That's 10 nibbles which are encoded in 0.5 bytes each"_, though? If you were to store this Nibbles program to a file (assuming that's possible), wouldn't the file be 10 bytes in size?

Comment: You can compress it using nibbles -c and it really would be stored as 5 bytes since each instruction will only require 4 bits. The main idea is that you codegolf like normal using ascii but essentially get to divide by 2 at the end (with a few exceptions). Check out the webpage tutorial which explains this better.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

Saved 6 bytes thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh) and 2 more bytes thanks to [@Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)!

```javascript
a=>a.map(i=n=>i[n]=i[n]+1||n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQCPTNs/WLjM6L9YWRGgb1tTkaf635oqONtSBQTMYjI0FawHqTc7PK87PSdXLyU/XSNNI1NTU/A8A)

### Explanation

`map`s over the input (`a`) (storing the `map`ping function as `i`) and returns the value of setting index `n` in `i` to the previous value + `1`, or the input (`n`), which will increment the input each following time it's encountered.

Comment: `a=>a.map(b=c=>c+~(b[c]=~-b[c]))`

Comment: Of course... That's what "up with the baby golfing" does for me... Thank you!

Comment: Weird, this actually works. I know JavaScript and am quite familiar with arrow functions, but this `b=c=>` syntax completely baffles me. @Dom care to explain?

Comment: Added a bit of an explanation @richardec, but basically `x=y=>...` is storing the function in `x`, easier to visualise with parentheses and spaces: `const x = (y) => ...`. Hope that helps!

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQCPTNs/WLjM6L9YWRGgb1tTkaf5Pzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI04g21IFAIxCM1dT8DwA). Was about to post it myself then I spotted yours.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Shaggy! Really simple to follow now too!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 47 bytes

```c
b;f(*a,n){for(b=0;n--;b+=*a-b-*++a?-b:1)*a+=b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPbbpwwEH3PV4yQNuJiq9yjxKV5qPoVu/sALKQoqXe1IHXVFb9eOmtjbJM8RUXGt3PmcpihpvVbyV@mqWKt65eEe9f2eHarImScUlYFhV/SivpBUD7T6iny/DIoKjZOHR/gV9lx14PrHeBzuxiafoi2eyjgGhGICSQjW4B4ASR2g21GIhkhAT0MODUdRKF615NhkUkLmhGw3pSAOR5xGFa5FWdJd2RKpy9ovaQJzUQqlEsil1QumVxybS7OXFr33Z/m2LrCifdlPvnySMBAYxuNbTSx0cRGUxtNbTSz0cxGcxvNPUNHczk19dAcPiy5AmMTnGuOX33F0qWPFGtNSU1HovTRUnSxE9fr8GYLYEUoOqbx0gJ4mxN4EC0QhSvT3JIl@FKf7gNFlczlexCtXm8TvU31NtNb1SL1kfcD1D/Ls49zU782Z@nf2V1@xLvL43d8M4eAeU6c2Rp/X3BvMjp@aC5oFrJ5@1XVVQXUpV1uGASBYHvCmfy1ddujO9n6grNnJgx8Rvk79HRGvHWdrePpS53onCQmyEV8z4hrmm/6zQFld8837U8OzsO22xsux3cR90C/gR3WHQhwj9nKGsxhKeZH4k5l3yMn@lT@0lYs9/ciaSgwHq7s/wnd9DuOTNUxt2jKZLwbp791@1a@9BP9/Q8)

Inputs a pointer to an array of integers and its length (because pointers in C carry no length info).
Incrementally increments identical elements in place.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

```c
f(r,l,i)int*r;{for(i=0;--l;*r-=i*=r[i--]==*++r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDtboMwDPxNnsJimkTA2WBdp00pe5GKHxUfqyUGVaCbtIpnZzbQdZUqJ4ovuXPsy81Hno931OT1sShh0/UFtQ/797EKHNZImpo@dPZUtS6gNLbG1DZ0JqUwdVsyJkvTMIqctsP41VIBB8eCnWMy64ATBM6gLhsNJ@V976kuIWBojJ7JVeDfF@AjhMyOIm2Vdzj2XeD7nA5K1J87agLRC@jLru@2GaRSL8EnXKGckkkuKMZzzC9JPK/rrTyzxst6nsQSbxyLcC6rBlTc8t@vK4QXhDXCK0KSMFCDVewQyNTANvEw0iazp24t0Kajn7KtZPJOPy6A2ZrfeGipuvjEoukvysSJs51SBycb@ba6hrdJFxO9qZfoX91BDeMv)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅγL<+˜
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOu5zT422qfn/P8fbaijgEAGEGyEhI2B2AQFxwIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8Ot5zb72GifnvNf5390tKGOAgIZQLAREjYGYhMUHKujANJlBJSDMiE8kABUDKgOgRCKYOYbGqATIDW6pjoKKNgEaBsSsgQiJLPg1sbGAgA).

```
€kā<α+
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UdOa7CONNuc2av//H22oo4BABhBshISNgdgEBccCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f9HTWuyjzTanNuo/V@HCyTFVZ6RmZOqUJSamKKQmceVks@loKCfX1CiDzEBSqEZaqOgAlabl/o/2lBHAYEMINgICRsDsQkKjuUCaTICSkFYEA6IDxECKkIguBKY2YYG6ARQia6pjgIKNgFahIQsgQhhEtzKWC4A).

```
γεεN+,
```

Outputs each item newline separated.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZzW89t9dPW@f8/2lBHAYEMINgICRsDsQkKjv2vq5uXr5uTWFUJAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX2nLpeRfWgLh6fw/t/nc1nNb/bR1/tfWHtpm/z862lBHAYEMINgICRsDsQkKjtVRAOkyAspBmRAeSAAqBlSHQAhFMPMNDdAJkBpdUx0FFGwCtA0JWQIRkllwa2Nj/@vq5uXr5iRWVQIA).

I have the feeling 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) should be possible, but haven't been able to find it yet. Here are three different 6-bytes approached, though.

**Explanation:**

```python
Åγ      # Run-length encode the (implicit) input-list, pushing the lists of items and
        # counts separated to the stack
  L     # Transform each count to an inner list in the range [1,count]
   <    # Decrease each by 1 to make the ranges [0,count)
    +   # Add the run-length items to each inner list
     ˜  # Flatten the list of lists
        # (after which this list is output implicitly as result)

€       # Map each item in the (implicit) input-list to:
 k      #  The 0-based index of its first occurrence
  ā     # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
   <    # Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0,length)
    α   # Get the absolute difference of each with the indices
     +  # And add each to the (implicit) input-items
        # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
        
γ       # Split the (implicit) input-list into parts of equal adjacent items
 ε      # Map each inner list to:
  ε     #  Map each integer to:
   N+   #   Add the 0-based (inner) map-index
     ,  #   Pop and output it with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 34 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{if($c-$_){$c=$i=$_}($i++)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Ra4MwGHz3V3xItir9Arq2G2UIlrI9DTbWvY0hXZa2Ka52JmUD6293iWmrliYR9e6@u9w2@@W5XPE0pSzLeUUWUVGReb6U@6tCLDzCKEn8grCIiIgkpUdEv@@XVek4seeAXhh7bog3OHARDh9@izCIxhq6/sFhSxTgYRtJUE90BcYlDOzpPEdPw4QH0LwN0r4GHWFzhnjcYxwbBwvSAdIby47wFu80Gwbnl7B1Tk211vb1YQ@PWf4wZyv6/LnmTEFRTxLFpZrOJZ/ImcrFZolA@N9WC/gXRECSrspA5xNA5TYVCnrYu5ACfZJAaV1yLnepmsgnIZV2uiYLiI9ubYVJ6WjpOhMbE@DUsveX2XQnVfZtQz5i28Ws2Y4xLmXjAJT/NJXuT0L3TQeDSXYvlWqEr2dXskzplE71Dw)

-2 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Ra4MwGHz3V3xItir9Arq2G2UIlrI9DTbWvY0hXZa2Ka52JmUD6293iWmrliYR9e6@u9w2@@W5XPE0pSzLeUUWUVGReb6U@6tCLDzCKEn8grCIiIgkpUdEv@@XVek4seeAXhh7bog3OHARDh9@izCIxhq6/sFhSxTgYRtJUE90BcYlDOzpPEdPw4QH0LwN0r4GHWFzhnjcYxwbBwvSAdIby47wFu80Gwbnl7B1Tk211vb1YQ@PWf4wZyv6/LnmTEFRTxLFpZrOJZ/ImcrFZolA@N9WC/gXRECSrspA5xNA5TYVCnrYu5ACfZJAaV1yLnepmsgnIZV2uiYLiI9ubYVJ6WjpOhMbE@DUsveX2XQnVfZtQz5i28Ws2Y4xLmXjAJT/NJXuT0L3TQeDSXYvlWqEr2dXskzplE71Dw "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") ?

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 64 bytes

```java
l->{int i=0;for(int x:l)System.out.println(x+i++-l.indexOf(x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LasMwEDxHX6GjjGuRPk5VYig5BVp6yLH0oMqSWVeWjLQKDsHf7sp90JZ22WFfwwzbyaOsuuZ1hn7wAWmXZ54QLDfJKQTv@M67mHodBPnDuYeI/6zvQpCnKMiQXiwoqqyMkT5IcPRMaI7PfUSJuRw9NLTPV3bAAK59eqYytLHI5NWX92Zx2uwd6laHuqZmO9uqPoNDCtu1MD6wpR9vbXE4RdQ99wn5kOXQOjaWUJaV5eAaPT4aNhaFmGZBVoZLpfSAbJHn3rDLC/qd6w9c/cB1xs0vZKn3nyYyzW8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 35 bytes

```
a->b=x;[if(b-t,c=0;b=t,b+c++)|t<-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LCsMgEPyVJSfFXTB9HEpqfkQ8rAGLUIoEDyn0363SR9LCzDIzDLOJ50iXVAKYwjR6sww2BuEp42T04E1Gryal5COfiV3hlK53wUAjpDnecpVdMx0EwVIiWNsj7BD2ruoqX64F70wjrFhLvf7w/7QOHRF@eEDY4lSx2fq@dU6WJw)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 36 bytes

```
a->p=0;[t+polcoeff(p+=x^t,t)-1|t<-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LCsIwEPyVpaeE7kLi4yCa/kiIsIiRQrFLyUHBf48JPlqFmWVmGGaFp54ukiO4zNSJM3ufWhmH03iOUUnrbseESZN9pANxyCwy3BUDdSBTf01FNtU0EBVrjeC9RVghrEPRRb5cDd6ZQZgxl6z58P/UDm0RfrhBWGJXsNj6vg1B5yc)

Based on [my PARI/GP answer to another challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178726/9288).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
+VsUM.g
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BVsUM.g&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+10%2C+10%2C+100%2C+100%2C+100%2C+100%5D%0A%5B-5%2C+-5%2C+-5%2C+-5%2C+-4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+9%2C+9%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%5D&debug=0)

##### Explanation:

```
+VsUM.g    | Full code
+VsUM.gkQQ | with implicit variables
-----------+----------------------------------
     .gkQ  | Group identical runs in the input
   UM      | Convert each run to [0..length)
  s        | Flatten
+V       Q | Vector add to input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ġıŻ+
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCVBMSVDNCVCMSVDNSVCQiUyQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PSU1QjElMkMlMjAxJTJDJTIwMSUyQyUyMDElMkMlMjAxMCUyQyUyMDEwJTJDJTIwMjAlMkMlMjAyMCUyQyUyMDIwJTJDJTIwMzAlMkMlMjA0MCUyQyUyMDQwJTJDJTIwNDAlMkMlMjA0MCU1RCZmbGFncz1TZQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
ġıŻ+  # Implicit input
ġ     # Group consecutive items together
 ı    # Map over each group:
  Ż   #  Push [0..length)
   +  #  Add this to the group
      # Implicit output
```